# How to perform Like in SQL on a column with '%' in the data?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, criteria-api

I am using oracle database and writing the likeness filter for the persistence layer and want to perform likeness on a column that can possibly have `'%'` in it's data.

To filter data I am writing the query for likeness using `LIKE` clause as

```
select * from table where columnName like '%%%';
```

which is returning all the values but I only want the rows that contains `'%'` in the columnName. 
Not sure what escape character to use or what to do to filter on the `'%'` symbol. Any suggestions??

Also, I have to do the same thing using Criteria api in java and have no clues about putting escape character there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an escape character.

```
where columnName like '%$%%' escape '$'
```

Comment: I have already tried '\' it didn't work. But second one worked. How can I do that using Criteria api??

Comment: You pass the escape character as the third argument. https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/criteria/CriteriaBuilder/like_Expression__String_char

Comment: There is no "built-in" escape character.  See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52142

Answer (score 1):

`REGEXP_LIKE` might help in a rather simple manner.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'abc%def' from dual union all
  3     select '%12345&' from dual union all
  4     select '%abc12%' from dual union all
  5     select '1234567' from dual
  6    )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  where regexp_like(col, '%');

COL
-------
abc%def
%12345&
%abc12%

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood it correctly the answer from the @Littlefoot is correct(and I will up-vote it now). I will just add more details because you are looking for name of the columns of your table "I only want the rows that contains '%' in the columnName".

Here is the table I have created:

```
CREATE TABLE "table_WITH%" ("numer%o" number
                            , name varchar2(50)
                            , "pric%e" number
                            , coverage number
                            , activity_date date);
```

Then this query gives me the correct answer:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_WITH%'
AND regexp_like(COLUMN_NAME, '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer using the `escape` clause of the `like` command is correct in the general case.

In your specific case (searching for a single character, anywhere in a string), a simpler method is to use `instr`, e.g.

```
where instr(columnname, '%') > 0
```